# AWS IoT SDK for Swift connection callback never executes

Tags: ios, swift, aws-iot

I am trying to use iPhones as IoT devices to receive messages using AWS. I am using provided AWS Swift sample code to establish a connection and the iotDataManager callback never executes or gives any indication of attempting to connect.

'''
iotDataManager.connect(withClientId: CLIENT_ID,
cleanSession: true,
certificateId: thingCert,
statusCallback: mqttEventCallback)
'''

I have tried using different callback functions, different configuration settings, and different connection methods to even try and get any type of response from the process. Stepping through the function execution does not give any clear indication of something going wrong.